# How to tag users with TeleBot Library

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I made a Telegram bot using the telebot library, which needs a function that if a user in the group replies /tag to a message, the bot will tag all members of the group on the message to which the user replied /tag.

I tried a couple of functions but none of them worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.